# Huge difference between python and fortran difference for a small program

Tags: python, fortran

I am reading a file containing single precision data with 512**3 data points. Based on a threshold, I assign each point a flag of 1 or 0. I wrote two programs doing the same thing, one in fortran, the other in python. But the one in fortran takes like 0.1 sec while the one in python takes minutes. Is it normal? Or can you please point out the problem with my python program:

fortran.f

```
  program vorticity_tracking

  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: length = 512**3
  integer, parameter :: threshold = 1320.0

  character(255) :: filen
  real, dimension(length) :: stored_data
  integer, dimension(length) :: flag
  integer index

  filen = "vor.dat"

  print *, "Reading the file ", trim(filen)
  open(10, file=trim(filen),form="unformatted",
 &     access="direct", recl = length*4)
  read (10, rec=1) stored_data
  close(10)

  do index = 1, length
     if (stored_data(index).ge.threshold) then
        flag(index) = 1
     else
        flag(index) = 0
     end if
  end do

  stop
  end program
```

Python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import struct
import numpy as np

f_type = 'float32'
length = 512**3
threshold = 1320.0
file = 'vor_00000_455.float'

f = open(file,'rb')
data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=f_type, count=-1)
f.close()

flag = []

for index in range(length):
    if (data[index] >= threshold):
        flag.append(1)
    else:
        flag.append(0)
```

************* *Edit* ********

Thanks for your comments. I am not sure then how to do this in fortran. I tried the following but this is still as slow.

```
 flag = np.ndarray(length, dtype=np.bool)    
 for index in range(length):
     if (data[index] >= threshold):
         flag[index] = 1
     else:
         flag[index] = 0
```

Can anyone please show me?

Comment: Have you tried preallocate your flag []? I.e. using np.ndarray(512**3, dtype=np.bool) instead of list. Array have a random access, so you need O(1) time to access (and O(n) for whole cycle), while with list you need O(n) for 1 element (and O(n**2) at all).

Comment: This is normal. Python is generally much slower (but much more flexible) than a compiled language like Fortran. For such calculations you can try advanced functions of numpy (but I'm the wrong to ask about details).

Comment: @AlexanderMihailov thanks for the comment. But I am not sure how to implement your suggestion. I have edited my post to illustrate what I tried, but it has not changed the performance.

Comment: I advice you to have caution on what you are trying to do.  Of course you can always optimize python code to the extreme (and in the extreme it will never be as fast as Fortran --- that's another question if you want to know why).  But at those extreme points ... you lose a lot of the advantage of using python in the first place; its language paradigms are there to make code more expressive in its own unique ways.  when you fight the way that the language was designed to be used you should be thinking about using other languages that are designed specifically with your needs in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general Python is an interpreted language while Fortran is a compiled one. Therefore you have some overhead in Python. But it shouldn't take that long.

One thing that can be improved in the python version is to replace the for loop by an index operation.

```
#create flag filled with zeros with same shape as data
flag=numpy.zeros(data.shape)
#get bool array stating where data>=threshold
barray=data>=threshold
#everywhere where barray==True put a 1 in flag
flag[barray]=1
```

shorter version:

```
#create flag filled with zeros with same shape as data
flag=numpy.zeros(data.shape)
#combine the two operations without temporary barray
flag[data>=threshold]=1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works extremely well. Can you please explain me one thing. Why is "flag[data>=threshold]=1" so much more faster than if I write a loop like "for i in range(length): if (data[i]>=threshold): flag[i]=1"?

Comment: I really don't know, so I can only guess. I think there are two reasons. Numpy uses a lot of c code and it uses vectorization.

Answer (score 6):

Your two programs are totally different. Your Python code repeatedly changes the size of a structure. Your Fortran code does not. You're not comparing two languages, you're comparing two algorithms and one of them is obviously inferior.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @David but I am not sure how to go about doing this in python. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for python:

```
flag = data > threshhold
```

It will give you an array of flags as you want.